# How can I remove an image from a carousel in kivy?

Tags: python, carousel, kivy

I didn't really find anything in the documentation on this so here goes:

I know you can add a widget (for example, an image) to a carousel by doing

```
carousel.add_widget()
```

But how can I remove a widget? In my particular case, I have a bunch of images which I want to filter by search text. Once the search is performed, how can I filter out the images which do not match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have a [`remove_widget()` method](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.remove_widget) that works the same way as the `add_widget()`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `carousel.clear_widgets()`.
It will remove everything added to carousel widget.